# Matching a raw GPS readings to a route on a digital map

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, gps

I'm developing an android app that reads GPS location every 1-2 minutes (Low sampling to save power) while the user is traveling. At the end, I have a list of raw GPS readings of the user's trip. How to convert this to a route on the map?

This is called Map Matching and still an open topic for research but do you know any open source tools that deals with such problem? Maybe Google Maps provide a webs service that deals with it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is called MapMatching, but there is some research.
There is no open source map matching solution.

But your work is not only the map matching part, much work is also the import of the digital road network. Altogether that could be some months of work. I have done that for a map matching project for Transport for London City GPS Trials.

Much easier would be simply read the GPS evry 1-5 seconds, and you are ready, with a 100% correct route without map matching errors caused by invalid and or outdated data in the road map.

Comment: That's for a transportation app too. But if you managed to get the GPS reading every 5 seconds, this will drain the battery leading to high disatisfaction from the user. How often do you get the GPS readings in the final product?

Comment: have you measured the difference in battery draing, when recording evry minute compared to evey 10 seconds? if the user needs the app, then he will buy an vehice charging cable. on iphone battery could record 8 hours evry second.

Comment: That's a good point. But the app is for Android and batteries for most phones are not as good as iphone. I will research that. 
May I ask, what algorithm did you use to do Map Matching? I plan to use ST-Matching algorithm developed by Microsoft Research, it works with 2 minutes+ sampling.

Comment: i use the Mapmatching algo that i have invented for Tolling Solutions. it is, and will not be published. again i remind you that importing digital road maps is a huge task, you may consider to do the matching server side.

Comment: Oh wow. 
Of course it will be server side. Data would be collected and transferred to the server to be processed. Have you transmitted GPS reads in real-time or sent them at the end of the user session? Is there any open source documentation for the London project you worked in?
Any other advice concluding your experience would be of a great help

Answer (score 1):

You may read this paper: [Hidden Markov Map MatchingThrough Noise and Sparseness](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/jckrumm/Publications%202009/map%20matching%20ACM%20GIS%20camera%20ready.pdf). The algorithm mentioned in this paper is based on Hidden Markov Model which works pretty well for sparse sampled GPS points (e.g., 1-2 minutes per GPS point).

I have implemented the algorithm using C#([available here](https://github.com/liyaguang/TrjTools/blob/master/TrjTools/MapMatching/MM.cs)), you may refer to it.

Another open source java project of map-matching is available here. https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching.